# draw a grid behind a plot with basic R

Tags: r, plot

I use only basic R plotting functions. I need a grid.
But using `grid()` only works *after* plotting. The result is a grid *on top* of the plot. This looks ugly and make no sense. I need the grid *behind* the plot. Is this possible with basic R?

```
barplot(sleep$extra, col='red')
grid(col='blue')
```

[image]

Comment: It is not recommended to use Google. Use the SX search field itself or [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com) to take your of your privicy. You can search on Google using DuckDuckGo when using `!g` in the beginning of your queries.

Comment: btw: SX doesn't offered me the answer of Gavin.

Comment: Where could I found the docu about `panel.first`? A `??` doesn't work for it.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi if you know the link to the answer please close vote as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
barplot(sleep$extra, col='red', panel.first=grid())
grid(col='blue')
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.

Comment: the grid will expand out of the limits of the plot, because panel.first is called before the plot is made.